# Configure specific GeoServer workspace in NGINX reverse proxy

Tags: geoserver, proxy, nginx

I am using GeoServer 2.12 on CentOS. I have almost 15 workspaces in my GeoServer.

Objective : I want to share my specific workspace to my external users (outside users) so that they can use GeoServer WMS service to QGIS.

Steps followed :

1. We have installed NGINX on our side and configuring with GeoServer.
2. I have searched on web but not able to find an example, on GeoServer side they mentioned that one way is to '[isolated workspace](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/webadmin/workspaces.html#isolated-workspaces)'. Main part is how do I configure this with NGINX side ?

Comment: You probably want to take this opportunity to upgrade to 2.16 or 2.17 while you are changing things

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the bottom of the [manual page](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/data/webadmin/workspaces.html#isolated-workspaces) is this note:

> **The rule of thumb is that resources (layers, styles, etc …) belonging to an isolated workspace can only be retrieved when using that workspaces virtual services and will only show up in those virtual services capabilities documents.**

So you need to feed your virtual service endpoint through Nginx to work out what your virtual service endpoint you need to read this [manual page](https://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/configuration/virtual-services.html)

So it is basically something like:

```
http://localhost:8080/geoserver/topp/wfs?request=GetCapabilities
```

where you replace `topp` with your workspace name.